# Eloquent constraint by relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I get my data as follows: `$completes = Complete::with(['answers', 'survey.location'])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();`

How can I get all `completes` where `survey.location = 1`?

I've tried doing it like `Location::where()->with('completes')` etc but I need it to be ordered by `completes` without getting grouped by `location`

Comment: What is the relation between `Complete` and `survey`?

Comment: `complete` has a `survey_id`

Comment: one `survey` can have many `completes`

Comment: So you have in your Complete model `surveies` method or what its name ?

Comment: I have `survey()` yes

Comment: did my answer do what you want ??

Comment: Relax, haven't tested yet, will do in a few :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$completes = Complete::with('answers')
                       ->whereHas('survey', function ($query) {
                             $query->where('location','=',1);
                        })
                       ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

For more details take a look in the [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) in the Constraining Eager Loads section :)

Comment: Today you are my hero :), forgot about `whereHas`